# Why is my flexbox not working correctly?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have three divs in a row. The first should be a fixed with, the second should expand until it hits a "max-width", and the third div should take up the remaining space. It works correctly until the third div has text that reaches the entire width. Instead of the text just wrapping it begins making the second div smaller.

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="one">
    sdfsdf
    </div>
    <div id="two">
    fghfgh fghfghd sdf sdf sdf ssdf sdf gh
    </div>
    <div id="three">
    sdfsdfsdfsdfsfd sdf sdf sdf sdf sdfwef sdfwefs df 
    </div>
</div>

#container{
  background-color: red;
  display: flex;
  height: 100px;
  width: 400px;
}

#one{
  background-color: blue;
  flex-grow: 1;
  width:60px;
}
#two{
   background-color: red;
   max-width: 100px
}
#three{
   background-color: green;
   flex-grow: 1;
}
```

You can find a jsfiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/vxa15qd1/16/).

Answer (score 1):

You can try the following code:

```
#container {
  background-color: red;
  display: flex;
  height: 100px;
  width: 400px;
}

#one {
  background-color: blue;
  width:60px;
}

#two {
  background-color: red;
  max-width: 100px
}

#three {
  background-color: green;
  flex: 1;
}
```

If you want a div to take remaining space with `flexbox`, you can should the div `flex: 1` and give the other divs specified width. Otherwise the divs won't take the remaining space.

Answer (score 0):

You can try adding **`flex-grow: 1`** in the third **`div`**:

```
#container {
  display: flex;
  height: 100px;
  width: 400px;
}

#one,
#two,
#three {
  flex-grow: 1;
}

#one {
  background-color: blue;
}

#container,
#two {
  background-color: red;
}

#three {
  background-color: green;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. The #one div should have flex-shrink: 0 and no flex-grow.
2. The #two should have flex-shrink: 0 and flex-grow: 1
3. The #three should have no shrink/grow properties